# How can I find the line integral using these information?

Tags: vectors

Let $C$ be the curve join the origin (0,0,0) to coordinates (1,2,3) a defined by the parametric curve r(t)$\frac{lnt}{ln2}i+z^{\frac{3}{2}}j+tcos\left(\pi t\right)k$, $1\leq t \leq 4$.

vector field: $F(x,y,z) = 3x^2zi + z^2j + (x^3 +2yz)k$ ($F$ is conservative)

By $$\int _{C}\:F dr = \int _{t_1}^{t_2}\:f((x(t),y(t),z(t))\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$

$1)$ $x' = (0-1), y' = (0-2), z' = (0-3)...$

$2)$ The line integral of vector field: 
Sub $x', y', z'$ into $$\int _{t_1}^{t_2}\:f((x(t),y(t),z(t))\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$

MEOTHOD2:The other way I learned is Find the r'(t) and |r'(t)|

Then$$\int _{C}\:F dr = \int _{t_1}^{t_2}\:r'(t)|r'(t)| dt$$
P.S. I can't even finish it therefore i deleted the second method...(smell of clculate mistake...

Update:
[image]

Comment: What are the start and end points? It says origin is the start point then should it not be $(0, 0, 0)$ instead of $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$? Also, what is the end point $(c, c, c)$ or $(x_c, y_c, z_c)$? Also in the vector field, are $a, b, c$ constants?

Comment: I want to know how to do it instead of let others finish it(And i can only finish one way... therefore i did't type the question out... In this question I am confused of which ways should i choose cuz i learned 2 ways.

Comment: I orginally gave up asking this question....0///0

Comment: $r(t) = (\frac{ \ln t}{\ln 2}, z^{3/2}, t \cos\left(\pi t\right)), ~ 1 \lt t \lt 4~$ does not make sense. First of all $z$ cannot be there. Second, point $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$ are not on the parametrized curve.

Comment: I see you have unaccepted my answer which is absolutely fine but if there is something that you don't agree with, you may consider letting me know. That way I know the reason and at least I can try and explain.

Comment: Ohh... sry, I total forget to update the answer (christmas lol). The answer seem don't need to use the r(t).... Also not the way i thought...

Comment: I told you how to handle a vector field that is conservative. The question clearly calls out it is a conservative vector field. You can do by using $r(t)$ and calculating the line integral but for that you need to provide the correct $r(t)$. Did you read my earlier comment that the given $r(t)$ is wrong? The given points do not lie on the parametrized curve.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the given parametrization as points $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$ are not on the curve. Also it should be written as a function of $t$ only.

Coming to the rest of the question, it already tells you that the vector field $\vec F$ is conservative so you should find the scalar function $f(x, y, z)$ whose gradient is $\vec F$ i.e. we find $f(x, y, z)$ such that $~\vec F = \nabla f~$ and it is easy to see that $~f(x, y, z) = x^3z + y z^2$

If $\vec F$ is conservative then by fundamental theorem of line integral,

$ \displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r = \int_C (\nabla f) \cdot d\vec r = f(r(t_2)) - f(r(t_1)) ~$, where $r(t_1)$ and $r(t_2)$ are start and end points on curve $C$ parametrized as $r(t)$. For example, if the start and end points are $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$, the line integral would be $f(1, 2, 3) - f(0, 0, 0) = 21$